# Print HTML code with PHP

Tags: php, html, datatables

I have a list of data in my DB and I want to show that on a table. My problem is a little detail, everything works fine, except for the url link I wanna to put on a image, that is not working. I want that, when the users clicks the image, the browser redirects to one link, above is the line I'm using to try to link the url to the image (the image appears fine) and the url I choose is google:

```
echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<a href=\"" . "https://www.google.com.br/" . "\"><img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\"/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
```

Observations: $img_exch_addr is the address to the image I want the link on, and $arr2[$cont][0] is the name of the company.

You can check the page I'm using for test, here: http://www.bitcoinstats.info/exchange_volume.php
And the php line I showed, should be column "Name" (the third one).

I'm not a webdeveloper, any help would be appreciated, one more thing, I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) examples to make this tables, there is a lot of css and js code that I have no idea what they do there, however, when I took the class and id tags off the problem still was there, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do whith this.

Entire code of the table:

```
/************** Create Table *************************/
echo "<table cellspacing='0' width='100%' class='display compact' id='example'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>World Ranking</th>
            <th>Country Ranking</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Pairs</th>
            <th>Volume (24hr)</th>
            <th>Market Share (World)</th>
            <th>Market Share (Country)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>World Ranking</th>
            <th>Country Ranking</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Pairs</th>
            <th>Volume (24hr)</th>
            <th>Market Share (World)</th>
            <th>Market Share (Country)</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>";

//$aux =  array($row['id'], $row['Name'], $row['Country'], $row['Type'], $row['24hrVol'],
//      $row['24hrVolPosCountry'], $row['24hrVolPosWorld'], $row['24hrVolPerCountry'], $row['24hrVolPerWorld']);
$cont = 0;
while($cont<sizeof($arr2)) {
    $img_addr   = "/images/countries_flags/" . str_replace(" ","_",$arr2[$cont][1]) . ".png";
    $img_exch_addr  = "/images/exchanges_logo/" . str_replace("/","_",str_replace(" ","_",$arr2[$cont][0])) . ".png";
    $url_exch   = $countries_url[$arr2[$cont][0]];

    if($COUNTRY==NULL or $COUNTRY===$arr2[$cont][1]){
        echo "<tr>";
//echo "<a href='http://youtube.com'><img src='/images/exchanges_logo/BTCChina.png' alt='Youtube' /></a>";
        if($arr2[$cont][3]<0){
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . $arr2[$cont][7] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . $arr2[$cont][4] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.com.br/\"><img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\"/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<img src=\"" . $img_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][1] . "\" ></br>" . $arr2[$cont][1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . str_replace("BTC_", "", $arr2[$cont][2]) . "</td>";

            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>-</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>-</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>-</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . $arr2[$cont][7] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . $arr2[$cont][4] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\" ></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<img src=\"" . $img_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][1] . "\" ></br>" . $arr2[$cont][1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . str_replace("BTC_", "", $arr2[$cont][2]) . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . round($arr2[$cont][3],4) . "</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . round($arr2[$cont][6],2) . "%</td>";
            echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . round($arr2[$cont][5],2) . " %</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
  $cont++;
}
echo "  </tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag, already removed.

Comment: Why are you doing so much (pointless) string concatentation? there's no point in concatenation 2+ fixed strings when you could have just started out with one string to begin with.

Comment: Just did as @Jay Blanchard suggested, the code is cleaner, but still not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why this wouldn't work (although it really looks messy);

```
echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<a href=\"" . "https://www.google.com.br/" . "\"><img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\"/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
```

**Things To Do**

1. Check if you are successfully uploading the file
2. Check if you are uploading the file to the right place.
3. Check if you actually working on the right line of the code / right file.

I see no reason why the anchor / link wouldn't work in this code if everything else is right.

**P.S.** You can do this which is easier to read;

```
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold'><a href='https://www.google.com.br'><img src='{$img_exch_addr}' alt='{$arr2[$cont][0]}'/></a></br>{$arr2[$cont][0]}</td>";
```

Comment: Hi, the problem isn't to load the image, is to click on it and go the url Iwant...in this case google. Check the entire code I just put the...

Comment: @Ernanirst I'm guessing your problem seems to be the `else` part. Within else block you don't have any `a` element there! Wrap it around it as well.

Comment: @ Ilgıt Yıldırım YOU GOT IT MAN!!! Thanks a lot for solving this stupid mistake for me!!! Own you one!!

Comment: @Ernanirst my pleasure, I'm glad it is solved. I wish you best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

There is too much concatenation here -

```
echo "<td align=\"" . "center" . "\" style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<a href=\"" . "https://www.google.com.br/" . "\"><img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\"/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
```

You can do this -

```
echo "<td align=\"center\" style=\"font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.com.br/\"><img src=\"" . $img_exch_addr . "\" alt=\"" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "\"/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Just did what you suggested, the code is cleaner, but still not working.

Comment: Without see the code that loops through it would be hard for us to go any further. I looked at the page, but could not determine which images we supposed to be links.

Comment: @Ernanirst I made a slight edit to Jay's answer. I don't know if you copied it exactly without the missing semi-colon or not.

Comment: Hey, I just put the entire code there, @Jay Blanchard , it's the images on the third column the "Name" one...

Comment: There are no links on those images at all (on the site). Are you sure something else isn't removing them? Not even *bad* HTML is being output.

Answer (score 0):

and even you can write like this

```
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;'><a href='https://www.google.com'><img src='" . $img_exch_addr . "' alt='" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "'/></a></br>" . $arr2[$cont][0] . "</td>"
```

when i check ur link, and view your sorce code i see no  < a >  tag, this is the problem. http://www.bitcoinstats.info/exchange_volume.php
right click and view source